# Python - convert signed int to bytes

Tags: python, byte, converters

this code works fine:

```
an_int = 5
a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big')
print(a_bytes_big)
```

but when i change an_int to -5, i get the following error:

> a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big')

> OverflowError: can't convert negative int to unsigned

how can I convert signed int without getting error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

error messgae is clear , if your vaue includes signs  you need to pass `signed =True` when you convert it to bytes:

```
an_int = -5
a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big', signed = True)
print(a_bytes_big)
```

Answer (score 3):

The method [to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) takes a third parameter: `signed`:
So you can modify your code to this:

```py
an_int = -5
a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big', signed=True)
# or
a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big', True)
```